# Add a Model Attribute using ControllerAdvice

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I have marked a class with @ControllerAdvice

Added a method

```
@ModelAttribute
public void setSourceAppId(Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("myattribute","1234");
}
```

But this method is not getting called at all.

Comment: Please post your context configuration.

Comment: <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany" />


    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

Comment: It works for me. Post your class and your full configuration. You can edit your question.

Comment: Is it that Autowired annotation does not work ?

Comment: I don't know. You haven't posted nearly enough details.

Comment: I got it resolved, re-building the project helped. Thanks Sotirios.

Answer (score 7):

I have not yet used modelattribute with a setter method so i cannot tell that thats a wrong approach, but changing it to a getter will do the job. Also, you dont need to add it to the model yourself. Modelattribute is handling exactly that.

```
@ModelAttribute("myattribute")
public int getSourceAppId()
{
    return 1234;
}
```

Comment: Martin, it also works the way I have put in my question. Basically I need to set that attribute for all the controllers.

Comment: I see. So its not about the method but about the controlleradvice. Are you sure its found by the context scanner and instanciated? Ensure that this is in the servletcontext and not in the application context. (Same as your controllers)

Comment: yeah, i dont know what went wrong ..I rebuilt the project and it started working.